# No change when click on login button in ios phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

My index.html page is:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />

   <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/common.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jstorage.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        loadHeader("YSN Login", false);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Home -->

     <div id="header"></div>
    <div class="firstDiv"></div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <form id="loginForm">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textinput6">
                Email Address
            </label>
            <input name="username" id="username"  type="text" onkeyup="toggle(this)" value="">
        </div>
        <span class="ValidationErrors" id="userNameMsg" style="display: none;">Should be a valid Email Id</span>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="textinput6">
                Password
            </label>
            <input name="password" id="password" type="password" onkeyup="toggle(this)" value="" class="btn btn-8 btn-8a">
        </div>
        <span class="ValidationErrors" id="passwordMsg" style="display: none;">Should be a valid password</span>
        <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" onclick="loginUser();">
            Login
        </a>
        <div>
            <a href ="#" onclick="openSelfWindow('resetPassword.html')" data-transition="fade">
                Forget your password?
            </a>
        </div>
     </form>
```

and my loginUser function which runs on click of login button, I am calling restful web services through ajax

```
function loginUser(){
    var loginData = new Object();
    loginData.username = $("#username").val();
    loginData.password = $("#password").val();

    var loginObj = new function(){
            this.url = ysnURL + "userservice/login/user/"
            this.data = JSON.stringify(loginData)
            this.success = loginSuccess
            this.error = loginError
            this.beforeSend = validateLoginForm//validates the login form
    }
    tugnavAjaxPOST(loginObj);
}

function loginSuccess(data){
    console.debug(JSON.stringify(data));
    stopSpinner();
    if(data.success == "true"){
        setSession($.parseJSON(data.message));
        var ref = openSelfWindow("dashboard.html");
    }
    else{
        showAlert("YSN Login", data.message, function(){});
    }
}

function loginError(data){
    console.debug(JSON.stringify(data));
    stopSpinner();
    showAlert("YSN Login", "Error while logging to YSN", function(){});
}
```

I am ruuning this app on ios simulator, when I click on resetpassword link it takes me to the next page but clicking on login button does not show any alert or in simple words screen remains same.The same code is running properly for android but not for ios,even I have included the cordova.js file for ios then also the problem remains same.

Comment: Link for android tag? I didn't get it what you are trying to ask me

Comment: Please describe your issue in detail

Comment: My question is that when I click on login button it does not respond anything i.e. the screen remains the same while for android it's running properly.

Comment: do you get any warning or error message when in emulator? I mean in developer console..

Comment: No warning, no errors because I think console.log doesn't works in xcode